# How to scale single sample for prediction in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a set of scaled data that is already fit to a regression model.

When introducing a single sample to be predicted, how are you meant to scale this input prior to prediction?

I could `concat` to the original dataframe, re-scale and extract the bottom row. But is that not creating data leakage? Right? Also I would have to refit the model?

What is the correct way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the model that you trained earlier itself to scale the test data.

If you insert that row in the original data-frame that's not the correct way as you are causing data-leakage , you won't get to see the real data in Production in such a manner.

Let's say you have more then one of such samples and you decide to model the scaler looking at this new data again this is considered bad practice and causes data-leakage , your original Scaler model that was trained looking at train data should only be used.

What's interesting to me is that what happens in case your train and test data have different distributions in that case no matter how well you choose your scaling strategy it won't work well with the test data , here is a useful
 [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-to-do-when-your-training-and-testing-data-come-from-different-distributions-d89674c6ecd8/) which describes the issue and possible solutions.

Here is sample to scale your train and test data , this is reproduced from - [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_all_scaling.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

## load the dataset
dataset = fetch_california_housing()
X_full, y_full = dataset.data, dataset.target
##split into train and test
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X_full,y_full)


## initialize the scaler
scale = RobustScaler()

### you are fitting the scaler and then transforming the data
## the scaler looks at the data in the train set and creates a model
## which will be used to transform the data
X_train_scaled = scale.fit_transform(X_train)
print(X_train)
print(X_train_scaled)


#### scale has been fitted once , you should be using this now
### on all test/ predict data that come in
### hence the below line only applies transform on the data
### if you are going to fit again that would mean data-leakage
X_test_scale = scale.transform(X_test)
```

Comment: But how do I use the model to scale the test data?

Comment: @LewisMorris see my naswer below for that

Comment: @LewisMorris - I have added code to give you an example along with the comments , hopefully that should clear it out

Comment: This is amazing !! I understand now.... You FIT the scaler to the test data and then you can pass in any data into the predict method. Thank you so much. I am forever greatful you have helped me so much.

Answer (score 2):

### This example uses `MinMaxScaler` to scale the data but the same principle applies to `all` cases.

**The procedure in summary:**

- Step 1: fit the `scaler` on the `TRAINING data`
- Step 2: use the `scaler` to `transform the training data`
- Step 3: use the `transformed training data` to `fit the predictive model`
- Step 4: use the `scaler` to `transform the TEST data`
- Step 5: `predict` using the `trained model` and the `transformed TEST data`

---

**Example using iris data:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.svm import SVC

data = datasets.load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train) # fit it on the training data

model = SVC()
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)

X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test) # apply it on the test data
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_scaled) # model prediction on the scaled test set
```

Hope this helps. Cheers